# SAS - parse portion of rtf to another rtf

Tags: sas, notepad++, rtf, notepad

I am struggling hard on this one.

I need to parse a portion of rtf1 document to rtf2 document. Here is the basic approach:

1) Open rtf1 in notepad and find the unique start point(line) and end point(line).
2) Copy portion from point start point to end point and insert it in rtf2 document.

I know how to insert the portion in rtf2 document but couldn't figure out how to extract the portion. The portion that needs to be copied is lengthy so I have to find a way to input start point and end point so I can use those two reference points to extract anything that falls in between.

Thank you in advance for your valuable input.

Zora

Comment: This question doesn't mention SAS except in the title and the tag.  Are you asking to do this in SAS?  If so, you need to describe some of what you're trying to do in SAS, or at least mention it...

Answer (score 0):

```
|.......before.......|....portion-to-copy....|.....after..........|
```

If I need to perform such a task, I use simple method (in Notepad, Notepad++) - you can try it, too:

1. With text cursor at start point, you can press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Home</kbd> and then <kbd>Delete</kbd>. This deletes all content before your portion. (Do not save the file.)
2. With text cursor at end point, you can press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+End</kbd> and then <kbd>Delete</kbd>. This deletes all content after your portion. (Do not save the file.)
3. Now you have only your portion. Press <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> (select all), then <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to copy it into the clipboard. **In SAS:** Press <kbd>Ctrl+Home</kbd>, then press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+End</kbd>. Then press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.
4. Paste your portion where you need.
5. Close your original document (used in steps 1-3) without saving.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have to however do it in SAS. :(

Comment: Here are [keyboard shortcuts for SAS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#awskeys.htm). Please see updated **step 3** above for SAS.

Answer (score 0):

Find `startPoint.*?endPoint` using Regular expression -search mode with `. matches newline` enabled. Then copy selected text to clipoard.

`.*?` basically means "match any character until end point is found".

Remember to escape any special characters when defining the start- and endpoints.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I would really appreciate if you could elaborate it more.